# Stern-Brocot Tree and sum of coefficients of continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions, continued-fractions, farey-sequences

Suppose we are given a continued fraction $$\frac{p}{q}=a_{1}+\frac{1}{a_{2}+\frac{1}{a_{3}+\frac{1}{a_{4}+\cdots}}}$$

I am trying to find an expression, possibly asymptotic, for the sum of the $a_i$'s for a given $\frac{p}{q}$.

I understand that this is related to the Stern-Brocot tree. In particular, our problem is equivalent to finding on which row does the fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ first appear in the Stern-Brocot tree.

Are there any results to this problem?

Comment: "first appear" = "appears" . Your hypothesis is right, as per the answer already provided by @dicksters : so you want to know the correspondence $p/q \to {\rm row\, number}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/ContinuedFractions.shtml

Has a nice explanation of the coefficients of a CF, $a_i$.

They can be thought of as the number of left/right branches in the Stern-Brocot tree required to traverse to the position you want. As you point out yourself, the sum of these $a_i's$ (minus 1) is the Row number in the SB tree. So, in a way, you already answered your own question?